# BFS making key list of *char list array, mostly indexing and mallocing

Tags: c, arrays, gdb, queue, breadth-first-search

I would like some professional advice for making a char *x array of strings (of const char names with different sizes) Would someone help with mallocing a list to fit the size of a structure name ( qSep->front->name))

Attempt 1:   Well my base case works, so I started making multiple print statements. The first one doesn't get put in. My gdb causes error at printf("Found in List %s has name\n", x[0]);

### Code and then data structures below.

```
size_t separation( const User *user1, const User *user2 ) {
    int len= 0;
    char *x;    

                                //use contains
    queueSep *qSep =(struct queueSep*) malloc(sizeof(struct queueSep));
    int count = 0;

    //pre-condition: the user is not the same as user2
    if ( user1->name == user2->name ) {             //str compare
            return 0;
        }
    qSep->front = convert(user1, NULL, count);
    printf("Conversion complete for %s \n",qSep->front->name);
    len++;
    x = malloc(len*sizeof((const char*)qSep->front->name));
    x[len-1] = qSep->front->name;
    printf("Found in List %s has name\n", x[0]);
    while( qSep->front != NULL) {
        //check if front of the queue is the finish USER
        if ( (const char*)qSep->front->name == user2->name ) {
            return qSep->front->separationCount;

        } else {                            //add all the neighbours on the queue with separation size incremented

        struct node *currAmigo = qSep->front->sepAmigos->amigos_Queue->front;


        if ( currAmigo == NULL ) {
            //is that a bad thing?
        }
        while ( currAmigo != NULL ) {
            for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                printf("List amigo for %s has name %s\n", currAmigo->data->name, x[i]);
                /*
                //if(strcmp(x[i], currAmigo->data->name))
                {
                    goto end_nested_loop;
                }
                */
            }

            //make a qSep node
            struct sepNode *node = convert(currAmigo->data, NULL, count+1);
            len++;
            x = realloc(x, len*sizeof(int));
            x[len-1] = currAmigo->data->name;
            //insert the sepNode into the end of the queue
            que_insSepqueue(qSep, node);

            //go to Next Amigo in top of Queue
            currAmigo=currAmigo->next;  
        }
        end_nested_loop:

        count++;
        //remove the node
        que_deqSep( qSep ); 
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

#### Converted Struct

```
typedef struct sepNode {

    const char *name;
    struct Friends_struct *sepAmigos;
    size_t *separationCount;
    struct sepNode *sepNodeNext;
}sepNode;

typedef struct queueSep{
    struct sepNode *front;              //front of queue
}queueSep;
//How to make a list

typedef struct User_struct {
    const char *name;
    Friends amigos;
} User;
```

## EXTRA ( to convert a node to say separation length)

```
sepNode *convert( const User *user1, const User *user2, int count) {
    sepNode *sepNode1=
    sepNode1 = (struct sepNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct sepNode));

    sepNode1->name = user1->name;
    sepNode1->sepAmigos = user1->amigos;
    sepNode1->separationCount = count;
    sepNode1->sepNodeNext = NULL;

    return sepNode1;
    }
```

Comment: When gdb stops at the `printf("Found in List %s has name\n", x[0])` line, print out the value of `x` and `x[0]`. Since you declared `x` as `char *`, `x[0]` is a char, which isn't compatible with the `%s` format.

Comment: What do you want `x` to point to? In one line you have `x = malloc(len*sizeof((const char*)qSep->front->name));`, which makes it point to an array of `char *`'s, but later you have `x = realloc(x, len*sizeof(int));`, which will make it point to an array of `int`s. In either case, it looks like `char *x` is not the way you want to declare `x`.

Comment: x[len-1] was called, but there was no initialization of x[0]. @MarkPlotnick That error did come up after I fixed the code, good catch. I believe %s is compatible with char but that was not the error. Thank you. Upvote or I close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pointer list

```
char *x;
```

You have indexes that need to be malloc instead of

```
   x = malloc(len*sizeof((const char*)qSep->front->name));
    x[len-1] = qSep->front->name;
```

Malloc the size of the first index with

```
x[len-1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(qSep->front->name));       //redundant sizeof(char) =1 
                                                                  //just to illustrate
x[len-1] = qSep->front->name;
```

Also, if anyone knows if I can just free(x); in one line, that would be helpful in a comment.